# Plugging Sensei into WP theme - Optimizer

Tags: optimization

I am currently building a WP site with the Optimizer theme. It's an academy website, using the [Sensei](http://www.woothemes.com/products/sensei/) plugin. I am having an issue with the wrappers, and although they wrote [this](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/sensei-and-theme-compatibility/#section-3) article on how to fix it, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please post your code so far.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I'm saying this right.

Wordpress hooks are triggers that allows you to manipulate a theme or plugin. You can remove, add or replace code on certain Worpress events/calls, without changing the original code. 
There are two kind of hooks. Action hooks to manipulate the Worpdress code. Filter hooks to manipulate the output of Wordpress (text, data, links etc.)
You can use hooks by creating Your own functions in the functions.php file of your theme.

The Sensei article:

- Your theme creates a wrapper with html divs around the content. The opening divs are after "getheader();" The closing divs are before "getsidebar();", if there is no sidebar then before "getfooter();"
- Sensei puts a wrapper around his content as well. This can mess up your theme wrapper.
- To fix this: Sensei has actions hooks to replace the wrapper of Sensei by your own theme wrapper.